# dom bftrip and bsort false dont work together datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using datatables in my report section. When I try to disable sort using following code, it works.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#report').DataTable( {
"bSort" : false

    } );

});
```

But now when I try to put the print and excel buttons on the table, the stuff doesnt work.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#report').DataTable( {
"bSort" : false
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print','excel'
        ]      
    } );

});
```

Now if I remove bSort:false line then it shows me the print and excel buttons on it. I want both of them to be show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#report').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print','excel'
        ],bSort : false
    } );

});
```